# How to make authenticated calls to Spotify in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, spotify

I'm trying to work with the Spotify Web API to get information about song analytics. This requires to have an access token to make calls against the endpoints.

So far I have created a basic .NET Core application with the Individual User Accounts Template so that I can log the users into my application through Spotify and then use the access and refresh tokens to make calls against the API later. I can successfully get my user logged into the application and request their user information, but I can't seem to figure out how to save the tokens in order to use them again.

```
app.UseSpotifyAuthentication(new AspNet.Security.OAuth.Spotify.SpotifyAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Spotify:ClientId"],
            ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Spotify:ClientSecret"],
            SaveTokens = true,
            Scope = { "playlist-read-private", "playlist-modify-private", "user-library-read" },
            UserInformationEndpoint = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me",

            Events = new OAuthEvents
            {
                OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
                {
                    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
                    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);

                    var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    var user = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

                    var name = user.Value<string>("display_name");
                    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
                    {
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, name, ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Options.ClaimsIssuer));
                    }
                }                    
            }
        });
```

Above is the code in the `Configure` method that enables the Spotify middleware that I got from the aspnet-contrib repositories. I have `SaveTokens` set to `true` but I'm kind of lost as to where they are saved at as I don't see them in the SQL Object explorer.

My guess would be to run the `Challenge` method in the Controller classes to fire the `OnCreatingTicket` OAuth Event everytime and save the information I get back in a model, but I'm not entirely sure if that's A. The right way to do things and B. if that would even work considering I would need to maintain the model contents once I return back to the Controller.

I've searched everywhere and it seems that .NET Core may still be too new enough to have any documentation on this unless I'm just passing right over it. Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you just call `await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("Spotify", "access_token");` to get the token from anywhere.